# Protect an office online add-on

Tags: office365, office-js

I am new to the development of add-ons for online office. I am interested although I have the following doubts:
When you make a vba add-on, there is the possibility to share it with other users and protect the code with a password so that it is not visible and can not steal our code. This add-on can be used in different machines just by executing or uploading the add-on without much technical knowledge.
In an online excel plugin, how can I share this plugin so that they can upload the complentemeto to their accounts online or to their own computers, but can not see the source code that they develop, similar to VBA?

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is that office-js add in is nothing then some web html css code that gets loaded in Office client Task pane. More info and high level concept here [Office Add-ins platform overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins). Some of the processing logic can be done on the backend side so you can definitely hide that part but interacting between Task pane and Office client is done through office-js javascript library. If all of your proprietary business logic will be javascript on the frontend than you might have problem because I think you can get to those files and reverse engineer it. Regarding deployments you can choose [centralized deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment) and deploy Office Add-ins to users and groups within specific organization.